# How to drop the columns in pandas with multiple condtions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas

On the below data frame ,I need to the drop the columns which are totally "None" , with "blanks and None", but not the columns with values and None

[image: data frame]

On the above table, I want Column A and C to be dropped because they are totally "None" or "blank and None", but Column B has some valid data at least in 3 cells, it should not be disturbed

how to give this condition in df.drop (pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test missing values `NaN` and  `None` like `Nonetype` by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), then possible strings by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` and pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with invert mask for test if all values are Trues per columns (default `axis=0`) by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
m = df.isna() | df.isin(['', 'None', 'none'])

df = df.loc[:, ~m.all()]
```

Or like comment, only in output are replaced values:

```
df = df.replace(['', 'None', 'none'],np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```